# Criteria for nb_epoch, samples_per_epoch, and nb_val_samples in keras fit_generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have created a simple cat and dog image classification (convolution neural network). Having training data of 7,000 each class and validation data of 5,500 each class.

My problem is my system is **not completing all epoch**. I would really appreciate if someone could explain the proportion or criteria of selecting *nb_epoch, samples_per_epoch and nb_val_samples* values to get maximum out of given amount of training and validation data.

Following is my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils.np_utils import probas_to_classes

model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5,5, input_shape=(28,28,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
r'F:\data\train',
target_size=(28,28),
classes=['dog','cat'],
batch_size=10,
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=True)

validation_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
r'F:\data\validation',
target_size=(28, 28),
classes=['dog','cat'],
batch_size=10,
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
early_stopping=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
model.fit_generator(train_generator,verbose=2, samples_per_epoch=650, nb_epoch=100, validation_data=validation_generator, callbacks=[early_stopping],nb_val_samples=550)

json_string=model.to_json()
open(r'F:\data\mnistcnn_arc.json','w').write(json_string)
model.save_weights(r'F:\data\mnistcnn_weights.h5')
score=model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, 1000)

print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

img_path = 'F:/abc.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28, 28))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

y_proba = model.predict(x)
y_classes = probas_to_classes(y_proba)
print(train_generator.class_indices)
print(y_classes)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**samples_per_epoch** is usually setted as:

```
samples_per_epoch=train_generator.nb_samples
```

This way you are ensuring that every epoch you are seeing a number of samples equal to the size of your training set. This means that you are seeing all of your training samples at every epoch.

---

**nb_epoch** is pretty much up to you. It determines how many times you iterate over a number defined by `samples_per_epoch`.

To give you an example, in your code right now your model is 'seeing' `(nb_epoch * samples_per_epoch)` images, wich in this case are 65000 images.

---

**nb_val_samples** determines over how many validation samples your model is evaluated after finishing every epoch. It is up to you aswell. The usual thing is to set:

```
nb_val_samples=validation_generator.nb_samples
```

In order to evaluate your model on the full validation set.

---

**batch_size** determines how many images are feeded **at the same time** to your gpu (or cpu). Rule of dumb is to set the largest `batch_size` that your gpu's memmory allows. Ideal batch_size is active area of research nowdays, but usually a bigger batch_size will work better.

Comment: and how does batch_size comes into play here? What should be a good criteria for selecting a value for it?

Comment: One last thing, my training data has 7k multiplied by 2 classes so train_generator.train_samples would be kept and executed separately or all at oune in samples_per_epoch?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Could you re-explain it in another way?

Comment: You said,  "in your code right now your model is 'seeing' (nb_epoch * samples_per_epoch) images, wich in this case are 65000 images."
My question is 65000 of each class or just one?
(as i have 2 classes each having 7000 images)

Comment: 65000 of both classes. THe generator is just picking 650 images per epoch from the 7000 cats and the 7000 dogs. In `(nb_epoch * samples_per_epoch)`, if you are following my answer and setting `samples_per_epoch=train_generator.nb_samples` , `samples_per_epoch` will be equal to 14000 for your dataset

Comment: Yes I am following your answer, since I have only 7000 images of each, and generator is picking 65000 images; (less number of images and more images to see) will it keep on looping on those 7000 images to make it 65000?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137829/discussion-between-azeem-ullah-and-david-de-la-iglesia).